# Problems using MongoDB's $graphLookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, graph-traversal

I have two collections. `sources`:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "0001",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "_id": "0002",
    "address": "123 Some Place"
  },
  {
    "_id": "0003",
    "phone": "5555555555"
  }
]
```

and `connections`:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "0001.0002",
    "_from": "0001",
    "_to": "0002",
    "probability": 0.8
  },
  {
    "_id": "0002.0003",
    "_from": "0002",
    "_to": "0003",
    "probability": 0.6
  }
]
```

I'm attempting to do graph traversal with `$graphLookup` to get a list of all the sources connections. This is the code I have:

```js
db.sources.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        '_id': '0001'
      }
    },
    {
      $graphLookup: {
        from: 'connections',
        startWith: '_id',
        connectFromField: '_from',
        connectToField: '_to',
        maxDepth: 2,
        depthField: 'numConnections',
        as: 'destinations'
      }
    }
])
```

This returns the `destinations` array that is empty. I would expect it to contain two records (0002 and 0003).

I'd like additionally to multiply probabilities during traversal so that 0001 -> 0002 = 0.8 and 0001 -> 0003 = 0.48 (0.8 * 0.6). I must be missing something simple here as I've tried to follow exactly how it's represented in the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the below query.

You will need two [`$graphlookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/), one for connections for each sources and the other for calculating the probability for each connection.

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) with [`$graphlookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) to get all the probability for each connection.

[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) all the array elements for each collection.

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to group source documents with respective connections and its probability.

```
db.sources.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "0001"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "connections",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_to",
      "connectToField": "_from",
      "maxDepth": 2,
      "depthField": "numConnections",
      "as": "destinations"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$destinations"
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "connections",
      "startWith": "$destinations._to",
      "connectFromField": "_from",
      "connectToField": "_to",
      "maxDepth": 2,
      "as": "destinations.probabilities"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "destinations.probabilities": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$destinations.probabilities.probability",
          "initialValue": 1,
          "in": {
            "$multiply": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "destinations": {
        "$push": "$destinations"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hi Veeram, could you take a look at my mongo stackoverflow issue? I need an expert eye. [mongo issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669390/advanced-mongodb-query-needed)

Comment: Nice job! However, this won't work in a real world scenario with a bigger data set. The reason being that there is no connection between the first and the second `graphLookup` really. So if there were more paths leading from different roots (so not '0001' in our case) to e.g. '0003' then those paths would also be picked up in the second (reverse) `graphLookup` and end up in the multiplication. Not sure how to fix it, though...