# Advanced MongoDB Query needed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB queries, and I understand the basics of find. However I haven't yet come to grips with $lookup, $project, $aggregate, $match, etc, which is pretty much needed to do anything fancy. And I need a fancy query  See tricky issue below:

Collections:

```
schema
{ _id: 1, name: “Schema1”, }
{ _id: 2, name: “Schema2”, }

device: 
{ _id: 1, schema: 1, organisation: 2 }
{ _id: 2, schema: 1, organisation: 2 }
{ _id: 3, schema: 2, organisation: 2 }

field:
{ _id: 1, organisation: 2, name: “cost”, displayType: “number” }
{ _id: 2, organisation: 2, name: “retail”, displayType: “number” }
{ _id: 3, organisation: 2, name: “project”, displayType: “string” }

fieldvalue
{ _id: 1, device: 1, field: 1, organisation: 2, value: 2000 }
{ _id: 2, device: 1, field: 2, organisation: 2, value: 3000 }
{ _id: 3, device: 2, field: 1, organisation: 2, value: 1000 }
{ _id: 4, device: 2, field: 2, organisation: 2, value: 1000 }
{ _id: 5, device: 3, field: 1, organisation: 2, value: 500 }
{ _id: 6, device: 1, field: 3, organisation: 2, value: “Project1” }
{ _id: 7, device: 2, field: 3, organisation: 2, value: “Project2” }
{ _id: 8, device: 3, field: 3, organisation: 2, value: “Project2” }
```

I want to query FieldValue.
I want to $sum all “value” where field is 1
BUT only those which “shares” device with field 3 with value “Project2”.

As parameters I have:

**The id of the field I want to sum, e.g. 1 (cost)**

**The id of the "project” field, e.g. 3 (project)**

**The value of the “project” field (id 3) which also must be met in order to qualify for summation.**

So my query should only $sum the “value” of id’s: 3 and 5

How can I do that in Mongo Query?

And would it be possible to add more contraints? E.g. the “schema” of the “device” must be 3, which should then result in a $sum of just id: 5

Comment: Can you add your desired output here?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri Sure, my desired output of my first question, would be as mentioned above the sum of id 3 and 5 of the fieldvalue collection, which would be 1500 and answer to the second question would of course be 500

Comment: Can you use 2 fields to store value? (One for 500 and other for "Project1". Why are you storing 2 data types within same key? This could make querying collection a lot more easy.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri Not possible here. FieldValues holds field values of the Device based on the Field. The same field can contain different values depending on the device it is associated to. Same field can be used on different devices but should keep device specific value. I am pretty sure this is possible using a Mongo query.